# How to get data from meteor server in events with Meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to get the data or document for meteor server in event.
Someone has the other solution from this.

```
// meteor in server
Meteor.methods({  
  findPost: function() {
      return Post.find().fetch();
    }
  }
});

//client template
<template name="Demo">
   <input type="text" id="input-test">
   <button id="test">Test</button>    
</template>

//client event
Template.Demo.events({    
   'click #test':function(){  
     Meteor.call('findPost',function(error,result){
        if(result) {
           Session.set('foundPosts',result);
       }
     }
    var posts=Session.get('foundPosts');
    if(posts.length>0){ 
       $('#input-test').val('Found');
    }else{
       $('#input-test').val('No result');
    }

  }
 });
```

In this example I use the session to get value for meteor method callback function so that I can use it to do something else outside the method callback function. Do someone have better solution to get value from method callback function or have other solution to get data from meteor server in template event.

Comment: you can use `reactive-var` package

Comment: Thank you. but if sometime I want to use the data that I got from server to do something more like: to iterate or loop or pass to the other functions to get   other result. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
Template.Demo.onCreated(function () {
    this.inputValue = new ReactiveVar('No result');
})

Template.Demo.events({
    'click #test': function () {
        var tmpl = Template.instance();
        Meteor.call('findPost', function (err, res) {
            if (!err && res.length > 0) {
               tmpl.inputValue.set('Found');
            }
        });
    }
});

Template.Demo.helpers({
    inputVal: function () {
        var tmpl = Template.instance();
        return tmpl.inputValue.get();
    }
});


//client template
<template name="Demo">
   <input type="text" id="input-test" value="{{inputVal}}">
   <button id="test">Test</button>    
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you. but if sometime I want to use the data that I got from server to do something more like: to iterate or loop or pass to the other functions to get   other result. what should I do?